# Custom Translator BLEU score for baseline model

Tags: microsoft-translator

I uploaded training/tuning/test sets and successfully trained a Custom Translator. A BLEU score of 28.5 is displayed in a red box in the Model tab of the web UI. I can download the translated test set along with the source and reference data from the Test tab in the model training details.

What I would like to know is whether this BLEU score is better or worse than the BLEU score that I could achieve with the non-customized Microsoft Translator? And by how much? Does the red color mean it is worse?

I know that I can call the Microsoft Translator API to get the non-customized translations for the test set and then run a BLEU scorer to get the difference, but I was hoping to see this in the web UI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are planning on updating the test results UI to display the baseline BLEU score, but at the moment it is not available.  We realize that this is an important data point, but it didn't quite make it into the Custom Translator preview.  The red color is meant to indicate that the BLEU score is lower then the baseline, non-customized, score.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looking forward to the update.